# Is there a framework like now.js for Django?

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, nowjs-sockets

I'm looking for a framework that would let me just update data in the structures and not to deal with queries and views every time.

I know, it can be better to use Node & express, but I've already tried, and feel that I can leverage Django better.

Comment: A half an hour silence tells that it's me who's got to make it :)

Comment: 10 days more and still nothing ;) ?

Comment: Some 8 years later, this question is judged to be off-topic.

Comment: @JamesWong-ReinstateMonica I hardly remember asking it.

Answer (score 0):

I know the thread is pretty old but to answer it :

I found this :

http://dajaxproject.com/

example from the website :

ajax.py

```
from django.utils import simplejson
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register

@dajaxice_register
def dajaxice_example(request):
    return simplejson.dumps({'message':'Hello from Python!'})
```

html

```
<input type="button" name="rand" value="Get message from server!" id="rand" onclick="Dajaxice.examples.dajaxice_example(my_callback)">
```

javascript

```
function my_callback(data){
    alert(data.message);
}
```

I couldn't get it to work with "production standards" ...

The real magic of now.js is also that you've got JS on both side and thus no objects to convert/(un)serialize

I was thinking about a setup like this :

DJANGO <-> NODEJS <-> NOW <-> BROWSER

Django could send objects serialized as json to node who would do the rest ...

I guess that would be somewhat tricky ... I also thought about going the other way around : meaning getting all django nice features (models,(auto)admin,templates,urls,middleware...)

I couldn't find anything as nice as django (contrib) admin !! If anyone knows ?